# Javascript: How do I ensure something happens only after forEach loop finishes?

Tags: javascript, foreach, node-mysql

I have a table in a database which has a list of `bad_words`and a list of `good_words` which replace these `bad_words` in the input string. This is how I'm doing it, the parameter `comment` is to be tested for the `bad_words` and replaced by the corresponding `good_words`.

```
function testComment(comment) {
    var words = comment.split(" ");
    var resultString = "";
    words.forEach(function(word){
        connection.query('select good_words from words where bad_words = ' + connection.escape(word), function(err, result){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }
            if(result.length != 0){
                resultString = comment.replace(word, result[0].good_words));
            }
        });
    });
   return resultString;
}
```

However, this just returns the empty string (the original initialized value). This is because the function returns before the `forEach` finishes. How do I ensure
 1) I'm modifying the `resultString` and not creating a new instance inside the `forEach` loop? Do I need to use `this.resultString = ...` instead? 
2) How do I return only after `forEach` has finished executing?

Comment: you need to understand how to use asynchronous code

Comment: I know I need a callback function of some sort, I don't know how to implement it exactly.

Comment: sorry, but when you say `How do I return only after forEach has finished executing?` that doesn't seem like you know you need a callback function - that seems like you want to return after the asynchronous functions have finished